# how to limit the amount of sql data that i want to display?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

example of what i have in my database :

```
sub-category | item
-----------------------
Fruit        | Orange
Fruit        | Apple
Fruit        | Pineapple
Fruit        | Cherry
Vegetable    | Potato
Vegetable    | Celery
Vegetable    | Ginger
Vegetable    | Carrot
Drinks       | Coffee
Drinks       | Tea
Drinks       | Coke
Drinks       | Pepsi
```

I tried to use the following code, but it only displays 1 item per category instead of displaying all the items:

```
SELECT SubCategory, Item
FROM ItemList 
GROUP BY SubCategory 
ORDER BY item DESC
```

What I get is :

```
sub-category | item
-----------------------
Fruit        | Apple
Vegetable    | Carrot
Drinks       | Coke
```

What I want is the following (example with a display limit of 2):

```
sub-category | item
-----------------------
Fruit        | Apple
Fruit        | Cherry
Vegetable    | Carrot
Vegetable    | Celery
Drinks       | Coke
Drinks       | Coffee
```

Comment: Please clarify.  You show you're selecting from a table with column `Item`, but the results you show do not include this column.  They include `category`, which is not in your original SELECT statement.  It's unclear to me what you want the output to look like, since the displayed results disagree with the written description.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most SQL implementations have a keyword: LIMIT <#> you can utilize at the end of your query, replacing # with the number of rows you want displayed. I don't know how you formatted your data, but if you drop that at the end of your query, it should suffice.

You cannot use the GROUP BY clause, because it will then only display one item per group. However, You can also use the ORDER BY clause, and this can be used for more than one item. For example...

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY category DESC,subCategory DESC LIMIT 5;
```

If you only want to display the top 5 from each category though, you won't be able to do that with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

*** Someone have changed the original question. The question is totally not the same as before. So my answer would not be useful. ***

I recommend you to add ID field to be a primary key and ID should be int.

Then you can use this code

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
where 5 >= (select count(t2.id)
             from yourtable t2
             where t1.category= t2.category
             and t1.id >= t2.id
           )
```

I hope this works on SQLite. I have tested it on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can partition by a column to and then use that to filter

```
SELECT
    SubCategory, 
    Item
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        SubCategory, 
        Item, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition SubCategory, ORDER BY SubCategory) AS seq
    FROM 
        ItemList 
    ) AS t
WHERE seq < 3
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx